# How to read an image in as a byte array using Perl?

Tags: perl, image, file, byte

I have very little Perl experience.

I need to read a binary image in and pass it to the `Image::ExifTool` module.

Here is my code:

```
use Image::ExifTool;

my $exifTool = new Image::ExifTool; 

open(IMAGE, $file) || die "Can't Open $file\n";
binmode(IMAGE);

my ($buf, $data, $n);
while (($n = read FILE, $data, 4) != 0) {
  $buf .= $data;
}

#'.=' is concat
print $file .= " test";

$infob = $exifTool->ImageInfo(\$buf);

foreach ( keys %$infob ) {
    print "$_ => $$infob{$_}\n";
}

close(IMAGE);
```

As far as I can tell, my above code reads in the reference file and appends at the byte level the binary data to `$buf`.

As per the ExifTool documentation, you can pass an in memory reference to a file as a scalar var to the ImageInfo method -- this is done above.

When executed, the Image::ExifTool module spits out the following:

```
Error => Unknown file type
```

Comment: Side note: your misusing `.=` and your comment on it is wrong. `.` is concatenate. `.=` is concatenate and assign the result to the variable on the left. You may have intended to change the value of `$file` as a side effect of the `print` statement, but I doubt it.

Comment: your `read` should use the `IMAGE` filehandle instead of a `FILE` filehandle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use Image::ExifTool;

my $exifTool = new Image::ExifTool; 

open( my $IMAGE, $filename ) || die "Can't Open $filename\n";
binmode($IMAGE);

$infob = $exifTool->ImageInfo($IMAGE);

foreach ( keys %$infob ) {
    print "$_ => $$infob{$_}\n";
}

close($IMAGE);
```

Comment: Does not work for .svgz files (returns 'Error' => 'Unknown file type') in `open(my $FH, '<:gzip', 'svgfile.svgz'); $infob=ImageInfo($FH);` Any ideas?

Comment: It does support .SVG, at least it supports it de-facto. The solution to parsing .SVGZ is to slurp unpacked content into variable and then pass it to `ImageInfo` as reference: `$infob=ImageInfo(\$svg_content);`

Answer (score 0):

open takes a **file handle**, not a scalar.  Hence `IMAGE`, not `$IMAGE`

This will cause you trouble later should you try to do a read.
I.e., you want

```perl
$n = read IMAGE, $data, 4;
```

to actually get data from the file.
Expanding on the previous code:

```
use Image::ExifTool;
my $exifTool = new Image::ExifTool;
$filename = $ARGV[0];
open( my $IMAGE, $filename ) || die "Can't Open $filename\n";
binmode($IMAGE);

$infob = $exifTool->ImageInfo($IMAGE);
foreach ( keys %$infob ) {
    print "$_ => $$infob{$_}\n";
}

$n = read $IMAGE, $data, 2;
printf ("read %d bytes: [%s]\n", $n, $data);

$ret = close($IMAGE);
print "close returned $ret\n";
```

Gives this:

```
GreenMask => 0x0000ff00
BMPVersion => Windows V4
NumColors => 2
PixelsPerMeterX => 3938
RedMask => 0x00ff0000
Planes => 1
FileType => BMP
<snip>

read 2 bytes: [^@^@]
close returned 1
```

Note that the read did not work properly--should have returned BM for the first two bytes of a bitmap file.  The reason is the open call does not take a scalar, it takes a file handle:

```
use Image::ExifTool;

my $exifTool = new Image::ExifTool;

$filename = $ARGV[0];

open(  IMAGE, $filename ) || die "Can't Open $filename\n";
binmode(IMAGE);

$infob = $exifTool->ImageInfo($filename);

foreach ( keys %$infob ) {
    print "$_ => $$infob{$_}\n";
}

$n = read IMAGE, $data, 2;
printf ("read %d bytes: [%s]\n", $n, $data);

$ret = close(IMAGE);
print "close returned $ret\n";
```

This gives:

```
Megapixels => 0.994
Directory => .
ImageWidth => 850
ImageSize => 850x1169
BitDepth => 1
<snip> 
FilePermissions => rw-r--r--
Compression => None
NumColors => 2
FileName => staves.bmp
BlueMask => 0x000000ff
read 2 bytes: [BM]
close returned 1
```

The read worked properly and the ExifTool also worked.

(Hoping the formatting is okay.  I'm new to this....)

Comment: Can you expand a bit? It looks like you are commenting the other (accepted) answer? In an answer, you should try to give a full answer that corresponds to the original question. Thanks. Also, try to use the code formatting, for readability.